# Pair selection for pair trading in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a function which performs co-integration test on two time series in R language(two stocks when their symbols are given as input. Ex. "AAPL", "MSFT"). Now I have a set of 100 stocks in an excel file with the symbols of all stocks along with serial number. How can I write a function using two for loops which compute the tests on all pairs in the list.

```
cointegrationTestLM_ADF <-function(A, B, startDate) {
#some code
}
```

Example: `cointegrationTestLM_ADF("AAPL","MSFT",'2007-01-01')`

Now I have to perform that function on all possible pairs of stock symbols which are indexed in an excel file. How can I do that?

Comment: Please put some reproducible data or at least show us what you have and what you want it to look like at the end

Comment: You may try to read in the excel and use `expand.grid(vec_A, vec_B)`.